# Invalid user-defined conversion: C++ error

Tags: c++, calculator, user-defined

I am making a (very) simple calculator program in C++ using Code::Blocks as my IDE. I am experiencing a couple of errors in my program. Please take a look at my code and tell me what the mistake is. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <conio.h>

int num1;
char Operator;
int num2;


void sum() {
    std::cin >> num1; // User inputs first number
    std::cin >> Operator; // User inputs operator
    std::cin >> num2; // User inputs second number

    // These if statements identify the operator and perform the appropriate 
    // operation

    if ( Operator == '+' ) {
        std::cout << num1 + num2;
     }

    else if ( Operator == '-' ) {
        std::cout << num1 - num2;
    }

    else if ( Operator == '*' ) {
         std::cout << num1 * num2;
    }

    else if ( Operator == '/' ) {
        std::cout << num1 / num2;
    }

    else {
        std:: cout << "Incorrect value/s entered.";
    }
}

int main {
    std::cout << "Press q to quit the program.";

    while(1) {
        sum()

        if(ascii_value==113) { // For Q
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std:: basic_ostream<char>' to 
'int' [-fpermissive]
error: expected unqualified-id before 'while'
```

I started learning C++ just four days ago, so please appreciate the fact that I don't know much about the errors. Also, I am unsure whether i need to include limits, so please tell me in the comments below.

Comment: What are the inputs?

Comment: The first one is the first number, the second one is the operator and the third the second number.

Comment: are you asking use to fix compilation of this code? seems that main is not declared properly and there are missing semi colon...

Comment: I have realised this thanks to oblivion's answer, I am sorry I did not notice this before, but i am just getting to grips with the language.

Comment: @SamuelCrawford I've rolled back your edits because they invalidate the accepted answer.  If you have further issues you should ask a new question.

Comment: If the comment is correct and the goal is to compare `ascii_value` to the letter "Q", just do it: `if (ascii_value == 'Q')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int main` is not a function declaration change it to

```
int main()
```

and `sum()` needs a semicolon.
and in `if(ascii_value==113)`, `ascii_value` is defined nowhere in the code

Comment: @OznOg missed that one :)